# How to avoid "Edit Session" conflicts in apex?

Tags: apex, service-cloud-console, website-integration, cti, concurrency

I am working on a project where sometimes the users gets error **"The record were editing was modified by Other User during edit session"** during SAVE.

I did my research and found out that Salesforce have "Collision Detection" in place to avoid these data Loss while Saving the record.

Is there anyway that i could handle this by using APEX controllers?

As seen from the screenshot, we don't have control over the External Webservice making an update to Salesforce. 
When this happens the User can refresh the data, **but there will data loss and our clients doesn't want to refresh their pages**  and enter all information again in Service console.

[image]

Comment: Did you found the root cause of this?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on where the record is being edited there are some workarounds you can use. None of them are ideal.

#### Visualforce Page

This most commonly occurs in wizards where the time it takes to input everything can be quite long increasing the chance for conflicts. In these cases, a timed auto-save can help. You can take this one step further and add you're own conflict resolution by comparing the in-memory copy to the one in the database and having the user choose which values to keep.

#### Standard Edit Page

In this case you might advise users to save edits frequently to avoid collisions. And if they encounter one advise them to open the record in a new tab and copy over their changes from their original tab which even though the save failed will still display the values on the screen.

Comment: This happens in Standard Salesforce Page in Sales Console(Lead). Our Business Team is not satisfied with us asking them to save edits frequently. Thank you for your responding Ralph.